# ¿ Cómo copiar todos los controles de un form en c# ?

Tags: c#

Buenas noches, quería saber si es posible copiar todos los datos de mis controles en C# con un botón, tengo labels, textbox, combobox, datatimepickers. He intentado hacerlo con el clipboard pero solo puedo copiar el último control digitado. Muchas gracias a todos por su ayuda.

Comment: En el diseniador de formularios de Visual Studio o en tu programa en ejecucion?

Comment: En el programa en ejecución, para que cuando de clic en el botón pueda pegar todos los datos por ejemplo a word.

Comment: utiliza foreach Control in Form.Controls  luego tienes que castear cada tipo de control que tienes para ver si coincide y asi poder recoger la propiedad que te interese

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes concatenar los datos de tus controles:

```
Clipboard.SetText(string.Format("{0}\n{1}\n{2}\n{3}", label1.Text, textbox1.Text, comboBox1.SelectedItem, dateTimePicker1.Value));
```

\n es un salto de línea.

Comment: Muchas pero muchas gracias amigo, era exactamente lo que buscaba, eres muy amable.